# Is asking about how to cite Ubuntu in a investigation on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm umming and aahing about [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783727/doubt-about-ununtu-citation) question. Does it belong on Ask Ubuntu? I would like to bring it to moderators attention without flagging it because I don't want to flag something not wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [help centre](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

> ### Questions that you may ask:
>
> - Using and administering official Ubuntu flavors including: Edubuntu, Ubuntu GNOME, Kubuntu, Ubuntu Kylin, Lubuntu, Mythbuntu, Ubuntu Studio, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Touch, and Ubuntu "Snappy" Core.
> - Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
> - Development on Ubuntu.
> - **Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical.**
> - Any question not mentioned below or here are great!

It seems like a valid question. But I don't know the answer at all - let's get searching!

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: I am going to accept you... When I can!

Comment: And where did you get that from?

Comment: edited. The [help]

Comment: But this isn't a "service provided by Canonical" at all! This is about whether one should cite the OS they happened to use in an academic paper. It has absolutely nothing to do with Ubuntu (and the answer is o, of course you shouldn't cite it).

Comment: @terdon Yes, it is a service provided by Ubuntu. The OS is a pretty big service.

Comment: Sure, but the question isn't about the OS or about any services (like Launchpad, or UbuntuOne) offered by Canonical. It's about whether the OS should be cited in an Academic paper and, if it should, what format the citation should take. Both questions would be better served on Academia.SE.

Comment: If it is about entire OS, the right citation would be "Canonical et al,  Ubuntu GNU/Linux, Isle of Man, 2004-2016" . Do not forget to also cite GNU and Linux.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, no it does not belong on Ask Ubuntu. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu itself and less to do with any services provided by Canonical. This is a well-meaning but confused student who thinks that each and every tool used in their works should be cited.

Ubuntu is not a bioinformatics tool and Canonical hasn't provided any services relevant here. Citing your OS in your thesis is like citing the company that made your pencils. In any case, the question itself just might be on topic on Academia.SE but it really isn't on topic here.